# Modx загружает файл без ошибок, но по факту он не загружается

Tags: modx

В адмнике Modx Revo загружаю файл pptx загрузка происходит без ошибок, но в папке файл не появляется. Другие файлы к примеру pdf, картинки грузятся без проблем. Тип pptx добавлен в uploads_files в настройках.

В админке авторизуюсь под admin с максимальными правами.
В источнике файлов все разрешения есть для данного типа.
Другие типы которые есть в разрешённых грузятся под этим пользователем без проблем.

По всей видимости что-то еще в CMS блокирует загрузку файлов данного типа, что это может быть, где искать проблему ?

Comment: Вы заходите под администратором? если под пользователем, то надо посмотреть, может у него изменены разрешения для загрузки файлов, еще посмотрите медиа->источники файлов, может там тоже переопределены разрешения на загрузку файлов